# Unity and Windows 10 1703 Update, Problems Launching Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-10

So I have a new problem with (potentially) Windows 10's latest patch (1703) and Unity 2017 (any)

Post patch the following behaviour is exhibited:
Starting a new project in Unity:
Splash Screen opens
Select Project (includes and location)
Unity starts the file structure and build process
All progress bars finish but Editor never launches
Unity.exe becomes an Un-Endable process in memory
Two copies of UnityHelper.exe load but do nothing (they can be ended)

Same behaviour for opening an existing project adjusted as follows:
Splash screen opens
Select Project
Unity Project Version Import Dialog will prompt as needed
All progress bars finish but Editor never launches
Unity.exe becomes an Un-Endable process in memory
Two copies of UnityHelper.exe load but do nothing (they can be ended)

In both cases Unity has been allowed to sit for 24hrs with no change in state.

Please read before comment:
System is an i7 w/32gb, GTX 1070, Windows 10 Pro 64bit and has run Unity for dev for the past 18 mos no problem
No hardware issues reported
1 hardware change (Oculus Rift added)
Unity has been completely uninstalled (including AppData files cleared and reg cleaned) and tested with reinstalls from 2017.1.2p3, 2017.2.0f3, 2017.2.1f1, no change

Roll Back of Windows 10 patch is not an option (compliance).

Comment: Have you opened a support ticket with unity yet?

Comment: I have, no response as of yet from the Unity team.

Comment: I have tried Win 10 Pro (1709) and Unity started just fine. Is it an option to upgrade Win to this build? As well, have you checked Editor.log? Is there any error, warning there?

Answer (score 0):

In digging through Unity Answer Forums it was suggested that we remove our shiny new Oculus from the equation.

Low and behold we have a fully functional Unity again.  Tested on 2017.1.0p3 and the stepped up tot he present release of 2017.3.0f3

This required physical disconnect of the HMD and Towers from the desktop and a reboot.   We did not need to uninstall or stop any of the Oculus services, just a clean removal of the device.

In meetup chats this has been revealed to us as "The Oculus Plague" and not entirely uncommon, I'm hoping either Unity or Oculus can get this resolved, discon/recon/reboot cycles are hard on the hardware, and knees.

Comment: Would love someone else to confirm but we did a full system reinstall (drive failure) and had everything working GREAT with the Oculus, right up until we reinstalled Java JDK (9.04) and now the problem is re-occuring.